# CreateJS make Cache Empty Taking continuously Memory?

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I am working on a Project in CreateJS have found stage.cache(x,y,w,h) method quite effective but as it is being called at many places in my code. i am calling stage.uncache() but still it is leaking the memory.. I want to ask is there any way we can check how many objects are there in the cache or we could make the cache fully empty ..

Answer (score 0):

Caching is a pretty memory-intensive operation, as it generates canvases behind the scenes. When you uncache, the canvas reference is de-referenced, so if you are seeing memory leaks, it is more likely that the browser is not releasing the canvases from memory efficiently.

If you are using StageGL with EaselJS, then it is much more complicated to release textures from memory, and there could be something more going on that is causing a memory leak.